# Getting CSS transition animation to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm currently playing around with CSS animations and I'm looking to take a flat hand and have the hand move down the page i.e have a blank page and have a hand move down the page. As such I have been unsuccessful.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id ="splash" data-role="page">
        <center>
            <img  id='Hand' style="position:absolute;top:-30%;" src="css/images/hand.gif">
        </center>
</div>
```

Now I've been following a tutorial and have been using the following CSS:

```
.handmove{

  transform: translate(0,1000px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,1000px); /** Safari & Chrome **/
    -o-transform: translate(0,1000px); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(0,1000px); /** Firefox **/
}

.objecttransition{

    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Firefox **/
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Opera **/
}
```

From what I understand is .handmove is used to move the images position from -30% to 1000px down the screen. But the objecttransition class is to allow this movement to animate from point -30% to 1000px down. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Now what I look to do is as the page loads I want to add these classes to the hand using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#splash',
    function()
    {
        $("#hand").addClass("objecttransition");
        $("#hand").addClass("handmove");
        });
```

I've also used the .ready() event but that also doesn't seem to work. I'm not to sure why the animation isn't working? Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xR6B6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess, the problem is the spelling,

```
id='Hand'
```

vs

```
$("#hand")
```

Use the same capitalization in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... Silly Error!! With the `.addClass()` I used hand instead of Hand.Change `.addClass('hand')` to `.addClass('Hand')`. I then used the .ready() instead of `on('pagebeforeshow','#splash',`. Thus we have:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $("#Hand").addClass("objecttransition");
        $("#Hand").addClass("handmove");
        });
```